# подключить свой dll к проекту visual stu

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

пытаюсь подключить свой dll файл, который был создан в visual studio 19 по гайду из документации майкрософт. при подключении выдает следующую ошибку. пытался так же создать dll через коноль и minGW но результат тот же,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на сайте написано, что файл мог быть создан с параметром "cls", если это действительно причина ошибки, то как его убрать ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: dll при сборке вообще не используется, для подключения используется библиотека импорта, которая у вас должна была собраться вместе с dll